# FullCalendar freeze on windws and not on Mac

Tags: angular, electron, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

Maybe someone can help me. I made an application with fullCalendar with Angular and Electron. When I'm on my Mac, it works very well but on a windows machine, when I try to drag an event, to resize it or to change the view, it freeze. Otherwise, when I click on an event, it's okay.
I though that it was because I didn't have interaction plugin registred but it's the case. Anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for any help guys !

app.mdule.ts

```
/Full calendar
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // the main connector. must go first
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'; 
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; 
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ 
  interactionPlugin,
  dayGridPlugin
]);
```

calendar.component.ts

```
initCalendar() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      locale: 'fr',
      firstDay: 1,
      weekends: true,
      allDaySlot: false,
      displayEventTime: true,
      allDayText: "Journée entière",
      slotMinTime: '8:00',
      slotMaxTime: '22:00',
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      timeZone: 'local',
      eventTextColor: 'black',
      editable: true,
      droppable: true,
      slotDuration: '00:15',
      buttonText: {
        today: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        month: 'Mois',
        week: 'Semaine',
        day: 'Jour',
        list: 'Jour',
      },
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek listWeek',
      },
      titleFormat: { // will produce something like "Tuesday, September 18, 2018"
        month: 'short',
        year: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        weekday: 'long',
        omitCommas: true,
        hour12: false,
        meridiem: false
      },
      eventDrop: this.alertChangesEnd.bind(this),
      eventResize: this.alertChangesEnd.bind(this),
      eventClick: this.displayEventInfoModal.bind(this),
      dateClick: this.onDayClicked.bind(this),
      events: [],
      views: {
        timeGridWeek: { // week view
          displayEventTime: false,
          // other view-specific options here
        },
        listWeek: {}
      }
    };
  }
```

package.json

```
"@fullcalendar/angular": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.5.0",
```

Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.3
Node: 14.17.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.0.3
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, language-service
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1100.3
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.0.3
@angular/animations                11.2.6
@angular/cdk                       11.0.2
@angular/flex-layout               11.0.0-beta.33
@angular/forms                     12.0.0
@angular/localize                  11.0.4
@angular/material                  11.0.2
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.0.0
@schematics/angular                11.0.3
@schematics/update                 0.1100.3
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         4.0.5
```

Maybe a version compatibility problem. I really do not know. Please can someone can give me a clue about this ?

Comment: Have you tried other versions of Electron to rule out a bug in Electron itself?

Comment: No I just try to delete node_modules files and reinstall it from windows machine. I will try to upgrade and check again.

Comment: I'm on electron version 17.1.2